# How to find the li.last and add css using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-lists

I have got an unorderlist generated programatically using code behind, The html markup is like:

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li>
     <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li>last</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li></li>
<li>
    <ul>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li>last</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

The issue is 
`ul li ul li a` is styled as `border-bottom: solid 1px white;` and I want to set `border-bottom: none`
for `last sub li`, Is it possible to find the last li using jquery and then modify the class, or
is there any better way to acheive something like this,
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('ul li ul li:last-child a').css('border-bottom', 'none');
```

selects the last `li` and changes its CSS `border-bottom` value, this uses the [:last-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/), [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/erCzv/1/)

in [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#last-child-pseudo) you can do the following :

```
ul > li > ul > li:last-child a {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

[Working example using CSS3](http://jsfiddle.net/erCzv/2/)

Comment: @MrA try using it within `$(document).ready(function(){ // here });` to ensure the DOM is ready before manipulating it ...

Comment: @MrA try adding the `a` in the selector

Comment: yep tried that two but the side menu still shows the border-bottom for the last li :(

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$("li:last-child a").css('border-bottom','none');
```

removing the bottom border from the last li's anchor tag?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you might consider a pure CSS solution instead:

```
li:last-child { 
  border-bottom: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS (will not work for IE8)

```
ul ul li:last-child { border-bottom: none; }
```